# How to find when GtkWidget was validated in Gtk+2

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I need to know when a GtkWidget was redrawn and validated after I change it's content (schedule a redraw).

Is anyway to get whether it's redrawn complete or need to wait more to get redrawn.

Comment: Why, and can you give some context on where it will be useful. There are quick a dirty hacks to work it out., but a redraw is fairly quick.

Comment: I have a GtkTextView widget and it was for logging. And there is a autoscrolling function. There is a poll function and that will be called every 20 miliseconds. scroll should happen just after the GetTextView was validated. Doing that before will not autoscroll to it's end completely.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get around what you need is to delay the scroll until GTK knowns how big the scroll area is. Probably the easiest way is to use g_idle_add(). Call-backs added to it will be executed in priority order when there are no other tasks needed to be done. GTK does use the idle functions at a high priority to do its redraws, but a default priority should be OK for you.

```
gboolena my_delayed_function(gpointer user_data)
{
    // The function that does the scroll goes here.

    return FALSE;
}

void my_function_that_shows_something()
{
    // Do some drawing.

    // ...

    // Schedule a scroll.
    g_idle_add(my_delayed_function, NULL);
}
```

As a note you must return FALSE from that call-back otherwise it will be called repeatedly.